# How to properly subclass a subclass of Python Thread?

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading, oop

I have two classes: `ContinuousWorker` and `WorkerA`. I would like to pass in an argument that is specific to `WorkerA`, but also still be able to pass in `Thread` configuration arguments for use in the the `thread.__init__()` function. How can I do this?

```
import threading

class ContinuousWorker(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(args, kwargs) #=> this returns Error: assert group is None, "group argument must be None for now"
        # self.Thread.__init__(args, kwargs) #=> this returns Error: 'WorkerA' object has no attribute 'Thread'

class WorkerA(ContinuousWorker):
    def __init__(self, argument, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.argument = argument

if __name__ == "__main__":
    child_class_specific_argument = 1
    worker = WorkerA(child_class_specific_argument, thread_name = "threadA", daemon = True)
```

**EDIT:** It appears the following is a working solution, can anyone confirm if there is a more pythonic way of doing this?

```
import threading
class ContinuousWorker(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

class WorkerA(ContinuousWorker):
    def __init__(self, argument, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.argument = argument

if __name__ == "__main__":
    child_class_specific_argument = 1
    worker = WorkerA(child_class_specific_argument, name = "threadA", daemon = True)
```

Comment: Looks good. But why do you need the class `ContinuousWorker`? Isn't `class WorkerA(threading.Thread)` good enough?

Comment: @Nechoj The motive behind `ContinuousWorker` was that I had two subclasses of `threading.Thread` called `EventWatcher` and `ChallengeWatcher`. They both run a while loop that checks if a termination flag has been set. They do this by having an attribute `self.terminate_flag = threading.Event()`. I decided to abstract this duplicate code (the while loop and checking if the `terminate_flag` has been set) into the class `ContinuousWorker`.